# How to find the timeZoneOffset added in Date object

Tags: javascript

I am working with two types of Date object.

```
new Date("2000-01-01")

new Date(2000, 0, 1)
```

In the first type, timeZoneOffset was added to the date but not in the second type. How can I identify the timezoneOffset is added or not to the date object?

[image]

Based on this, I need to add the timezoneOffset to the date.

Thanks in Advance,
Kesavan

Comment: Just always normalise and do new Date(2000,0,1,15,0,0,0) to make a generic date without thinking of daylight savings etc